# cordova platform add android error javac

Tags: android, windows, cordova

I ran

```
cordova platform add android
```

and the error I got

```
Running command: "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "d:\Users\Andy\Project
s\ionic-tut\hooks\before_platform_add\init_directories.js" "d:/Users/Andy/
Projects/ionic-tut"
Creating android project...
D:\Users\Andy\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must
fulfill at least one of these conditions.
```

I ran this from git bash

on running it from cmd it throws a different error

```
Error: Please install Android target "android-19".
```

I ran a echo %PATH% to verify:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLSClient\;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;
C:\Program Files\Intel
\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
D:\Users\Andy\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe;
C:\Program FIles\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform_tools
```

I feel like I am messing up the enviroment variables somewhere but I have checked it multiple times and it seems to be right.

What am I missing?

Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run the command `android` from CMD to open the android SDK manager.

From there make sure that the `Android 4.4.2(19)` package is installed. Let me know if this fixes your issue.